# Cannot create director using os.mkdir

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a folder so that I can write a file into that folder. Here is the code I am using:

```
module = 'settings'    
BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
templateFolder = BASE + settings.MYAPP_TEMPLATE_DIRS + partnerName

os.mkdir(templateFolder)

templateFileName = templateFolder + "/" + moduleName +".html"

with open(templateFileName, 'w') as f:
    myfile = File(f)
    myfile.write(templateHTML)

myfile.closed
f.closed
```

I get an error saying the directory does not exist. Would it have something to do with  folder permissions? or there is a problem with my code?

Thanks.

Comment: `os.mkdir()` does not recursively create directories - the problem is quite likely that the parent directory does not exist. Also, you should build paths with `os.path.join()`

Comment: Any reason you are not using `os.path.join()`? What are the `.closed` lines supposed to achieve? The `with` statement *already* closes `f` for you.

Comment: You can try `os.makedirs`, it will make all intermediate-level directories needed to contain the leaf directory.

Comment: @zhangyangyu, it's [`os.makedirs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs)

Comment: Ok. So here is another confusion I have. What is the adv of using os.path.join over a normal string concatenation? I can understand that if you don't want to mess up the directory paths then we should use os.path.join but if I know the path can I simple concatenate the path strings?

Comment: Leon, the primary advantage of [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) is that it's cross-platform, and will handle any problems with slashes you might create. Do a search on the subject, it's well-discussed!

Comment: os.path.join is platform independent but perhaps more important in your case, it deals with a few edge conditions such as whether a path includes an ending path separator. For you, your app behaves differently depending on whether MYAPP_TEMPLATE_DIRS ends in a '/'. And by the way, it would be useful to print templateFolder and see if it really does exist.

Comment: Thanks guys. Noob mistake. Should have used makedirs insted of mkdir since the apps is trying to create multiple directories. Completely slipped my mind.